# need help understanding closures usage in this code

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is a simplified snippet from some code I wrote for managing tablet gestures on canvas elements

first a function that accepts an element and a dictionary of callbacks and register the events plus adding other features like 'hold' gestures:

```
function registerStageGestures(stage, callbacks, recieverArg) {
    stage.inhold = false;
    stage.timer = null;

    var touchduration = 1000;
    var reciever = recieverArg || window;

    stage.onLongTouch = function(e) {
        if (stage.timer) clearTimeout(stage.timer);
        stage.inhold = true;
        if (callbacks.touchholdstart) callbacks.touchholdstart.call(reciever, e);
    };

    stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        calcTouchEventData(e);
        stage.timer = setTimeout(function() {
            stage.onLongTouch(e);
        }, touchduration);
        if (callbacks.touchstart) callbacks.touchholdstart.call(reciever, e);
    });

    stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (stage.timer) clearTimeout(stage.timer);

        if (stage.inhold) {
            if (callbacks.touchholdmove) callbacks.touchholdmove.call(reciever, e);

        } else {
            if (callbacks.touchmove) callbacks.touchmove.call(reciever, e);
        }
    });

    stage.getContent().addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (stage.timer) clearTimeout(stage.timer);
        if (stage.inhold) {
            if (callbacks.touchholdend) callbacks.touchholdend.call(reciever, e);
        } else {
            if (callbacks.touchend) callbacks.touchend.call(reciever, e);
        }
        stage.inhold = false;
    });
}
```

later I call registerStageGestures on a few elements (represented by 'View' objects) in the same page. Something like:

```
function View() {
    var self=this;
    ..

    function InitView() {
       ...

       registerStageGestures(kineticStage, {
        touchstart: function(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchmove: function(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchendunction(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchholdstart: function(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchholdmove: function(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchholdend: function(e) {
            // do something
        },
    }, self);
```

Everything works fine, however I'm left wondering about two things in the implementation of registerStageGestures:

First, is it necessary to make inhold, timer and onLongTouch members of the stage ? or will closures make everything works well if they are local vars in registerStageGestures ?

Second, is it necessary to call the callbacks with '.call(receiver,' syntax ? I'm doing this to make sure the callback code will run in the context of the View but I'm not sure if it's needed ?

any input is much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, is it necessary to make inhold, timer and onLongTouch members
>   of the stage ? or will closures make everything works well if they are
>   local vars in registerStageGestures ?

As far as `registerStageGestures()` is concerned, `var inhold`, `var timer` and `function onLongTouch(e) {...}`. would suffice. The mechanism by which an inner function has automatic access to its outer function's members is known as "closure". You would only need to set `stage.inhold`, `stage.timer` and `stage.onLongTouch` if some other piece of code needs access to these settings as properties of `stage`.

> Second, is it necessary to call the callbacks with '.call(receiver,'
>   syntax ? I'm doing this to make sure the callback code will run in the
>   context of the View but I'm not sure if it's needed ?

Possibly, depending on how those callbacks are written. `.call()` and `.apply()` are sometimes used when calling functions that use `this` internally. In both cases, the first parameter passed defines the object to be interpreted as `this`. Thus, javascript gives you the means of defining general purpose methods with no *a priori* assumption about the object to which those methods will apply when called. Similarly, you can call a method of an object in such a way that it acts on another object.

**EDIT:**

For completeness, please note that even in the absence of `this` in a function, `.apply()` can be very useful as it allows multiple parameters to be specified as elements of a single array, eg the ubiquitous `jQuery.when.apply(null, arrayOfPromises)...`

Answer (score 1):

There are some simple answers, here.

First, closure:

Closure basically says that whatever is defined **inside** of a function, has access to the rest of that function's contents.
And all of those contents are guaranteed to stay alive (out of the trash), until there are no more objects left, which ere created inside.

A simple test:

```
var testClosure = function () {
    var name = "Bob",
        recallName = function () { return name; };

    return { getName : recallName };
};


var test = testClosure();
console.log(test.getName()); // Bob
```

So anything that was created inside can be accessed by any function which was *also* created inside (or created inside of a function created in a function[, ...], inside).

```
var closure_2x = function () {
    var name = "Bob",
        innerScope = function () {
            console.log(name);
            return function () {
                console.log("Still " + name);
            }
        };

    return innerScope;
};


var inner_func = closure_2x();

var even_deeper = inner_func(); // "Bob"
even_deeper(); // "Still Bob"
```

This applies not only to variables/objects/functions created inside, but also to function arguments passed inside.

The arguments have no access to the inner-workings(unless passed to methods/callbacks), but the inner-workings will remember the arguments.

So as long as your functions are being created in the same scope as your values (or a child-scope), there's access.

`.call` is trickier.

You know what it does (replaces `this` inside of the function with the object you pass it)...

...but why and when, in this case are harder.

```
var Person = function (name, age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.getAge = function () {
        return this.age;
    };
};

var bob = new Person("Bob", 32);
```

This looks pretty normal.
Honestly, this could look a lot like Java or C# with a couple of tweaks.

```
bob.getAge();  // 32
```

Works like Java or C#, too.

```
doSomething.then(bob.getAge);
```

? Buh ?

We've now passed Bob's method into a function, as a function, all by itself.

```
var doug = { age : 28 };
doug.getAge = bob.getAge;
```

Now we've given `doug` a reference to directly use `bob`s methid -- not a copy, but a pointer to the actual method.

```
doug.getAge(); // 28
```

Well, that's odd.

What about what came out of passing it in as a callback?

```
var test = bob.getAge;
test(); // undefined
```

The reason for this, is, as you said, about context...

But the specific reason is because `this` inside of a function in JS isn't pre-compiled, or stored...
`this` is worked out on the fly, every time the function is called.

If you call

```
obj.method();
```

`this === obj;`

If you call

```
a.b.c.d();
```

`this === a.b.c;`

If you call

```
var test = bob.getAge;
test();
```

...?

`this` is equal to `window`.
In "strict mode" this doesn't happen (you get errors really quickly).

```
test.call(bob); //32
```

Balance restored!

Mostly...

There are still a few catches.

```
var outerScope = function () {
    console.log(this.age);
    var inner = function () {
        console.log("Still " + this.age);
    };

    inner();
};

outerScope.call(bob);

// "32"
// "Still undefined"
```

This makes sense, when you think about it... 
We know that if a function figures out `this` at the moment it's called -- scope has nothing to do with it...

...and we didn't add `inner` to an object...

```
this.inner = inner;
this.inner();
```

would have worked just fine (but now you just messed with an external object)...

So `inner` saw `this` as `window`.

The solution would either be to use `.call`, or `.apply`, or to ***use function-scoping and/or closure***

```
var person = this,
    inner = function () { console.log(person.age); };
```

The rabbit hole goes deeper, but my phone is dying...

Comment: thx for this, it helped, I was looking for an answer that involved my code though.

Comment: Of course.  Show a man a closure, and he'll understand a function's scope...   Teach a man to closure...